# 301 Redirect using .htaccess does not work

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Here is my rule in .htaccess file:

```
Redirect 301 /George-Nelson-Bench-CT3005-EDI6.htm?categoryId=-1 http://www.mydomain.com/proddetail.php?prod=George_Nelson_Bench
```

But this is showing a 404 error on my website.

Some other code on the .htaccess file is:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index.php 
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Some other 301 redirection which works properly:

```
Redirect 301 /Modern-Classics_c8.htm http://www.mydomain.com/categories.php?cat=10
Redirect 301 /Sofas_c34.htm http://www.mydomain.com/products.php?cat=25
Redirect 301 /Bedroom_c2.htm http://www.mydomain.com/categories.php?cat=7
```

So, why the first 301 redirect rule is not working?
Any suggestions?

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect: `Syntax: Redirect [status] URL-path URL` … the important part here: URL _path_

Comment: @CBroe Yes. The _URL-path_ is correct in the rule. No?

Comment: The query string is _not_ part of the URL path.

Comment: Thank you @CBroe. The query string was the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're anyway using mod_rewrite its better to replace mod_alias based code to mod_rewrite which is more powerful and flexible.

You first Redirect rule isn't working because you're using a query parameter. Replace that rule with this:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+George-Nelson-Bench-CT3005-EDI6\.htm\?categoryId=-1\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /proddetail.php?prod=George_Nelson_Bench? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that query string is creating the problem here. I removed it and it works fine now. I did not use mod_rewrite for this. Thanks.